# About a case, which is about partial randomness, being halal or haram

Tags: halal-haram

I am about to finish a purchase which includes randomness in such way: there is a pack, let's say worth 5 units of money (a type of currency only valid on the specific site that I am doing the purchase), which will give me an amount of money in between $2 to $50. On the same site, there was a pack, containing only $2, costed like 2.4 units of money (2.4 units being in ratio with the previously mentioned 5 units) which I have purchased for once and can not purchase again. Due to the specific circumstances that the site puts forward, my on-site specific money will have no use at all for a (probably, according to my thinking on the given circumstances) really long period of time; in time, by levelling up my account, I can be able to purchase $10 pack, which contains no randomness but probably until that time, I will have much more on-site money (only if this can be deemed as an excuse to buy a $2-$50 pack) or I maybe will never level up my account, thus am not going to be able to spend the on-site money, according to my observations; to any other halal things on the site. I wasn't even thinking about getting more than $2 from the $2-$50 pack because I had (and have) nowhere else to spend my on-site money for a (as mentioned; probably) really long period of time and just wanted to get the money out of $2-$50 pack for short term reasons, without even thinking that by purchasing that pack I would maybe, kind of, be playing a game of chance (hence I am coming up with this question). To my thinking, I was doing the rational (probably profitable) thing by purchasing the $2-$50 pack. Although, considering the ratio inbetween the given units (2.4 to 5 approximately); purchasing a pack containing randomness inbetween $2-$50 for 5 units of on-site money and being content for $2 out of the pack (even though it is unlikely, still; I maybe can get more than $2 out of the pack) while there was a pack containing a definite amount of $2 that I have purchased (though, as I mentioned, can not purchase it again for a year, due to the requirements of the site) for 2.4 units of on-site money; would paying more then 2.4 units of on-site money for $2 and included randomness of $2-$50 (thus paying for the possibility of getting more then $2) be haram or halal?

Sorry if my description of the situation got too complicated. I will try to clarify the situation if I have left you feeling in need of it with my explanation. Thanks in advance for replying.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a gamble, and you know that gambling is prohibited.

“They ask you [Muhammad] concerning wine and gambling. Say: ‘In them is great sin, and some profit, for men; but the sin is greater than the profit.’… Thus does Allah Make clear to you His Signs, in order that you may consider” (Quran 2:219).

Comment: Thanks again for your answer temm. Apparently unlike you, I am not certain about this situation being gambling or not but I withdrew my order because of being unsure about its correctness. Although I am open to new answers that might give me better insight and make me certain about this situation.